# Retrying an operation after an exception: Please criticize my code

Tags: perl, exception, sqlite, cpan

My Perl application uses resources that become temporarily unavailable at times, causing exceptions using `die`. Most notably, it accesses SQLite databases that are shared by multiple threads and with other applications using through `DBIx::Class`. Whenever such an exception occurs, the operation should be retried until a timeout has been reached.

I prefer concise code, therefore I quickly got fed up with repeatedly
typing 7 extra lines for each such operation:

```
use Time::HiRes 'sleep';
use Carp;

# [...]

for (0..150) {
    sleep 0.1 if $_;
    eval {
        # database access
    };
    next if $@ =~ /database is locked/;
}
croak $@ if $@;
```

... so I put them into a (DB access-specific) function:

```
sub _retry {
    my ( $timeout, $func ) = @_;
    for (0..$timeout*10) {
        sleep 0.1 if $_;
        eval { $func->(); };
        next if $@ =~ /database is locked/;
    }
    croak $@ if $@;
}
```

which I call like this:

```
my @thingies;
_retry 15, sub {
    $schema->txn_do(
        sub {
            @thingies = $thingie_rs->search(
                { state => 0, job_id => $job->job_id },
                { rows  => $self->{batchsize} } );
            if (@thingies) {
                for my $thingie (@thingies) {
                    $thingie->update( { state => 1 } );
                }
            }
        } );
};
```

Is there a better way to implement this? Am I re-inventing the wheel? Is
there code on CPAN that I should use?

Comment: Lambdas are a great way to improve code reuse in cases like this. Although sometimes they can reduce readability, in cases like this they actually improve it a lot.

Comment: To clarify: I'm saying that what you're already doing (== lambdas) is good.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably be inclined to write retry like this:

```
sub _retry {
    my ( $retrys, $func ) = @_;
    attempt: {
      my $result;

      # if it works, return the result
      return $result if eval { $result = $func->(); 1 };

      # nah, it failed, if failure reason is not a lock, croak
      croak $@ unless $@ =~ /database is locked/;

      # if we have 0 remaining retrys, stop trying.
      last attempt if $retrys < 1;

      # sleep for 0.1 seconds, and then try again.
      sleep 0.1;
      $retrys--;
      redo attempt;
    }

    croak "Attempts Exceeded $@";
}
```

It doesn't work identically to your existing code, but has a few advantages.

1. I got rid of the `*10` thing, like another poster, I couldn't discern its purpose.
2. this function is able to return the value of whatever `$func()` does to its caller.
3. Semantically, the code is more akin to what it is you are doing, at least to my deluded mind.
4. `_retry 0, sub { };` will still execute once, but never retry, unlike your present version, that will never execute the sub.

More suggested ( but slightly less rational ) abstractions:

```
sub do_update {
  my %params = @_;
  my @result;

  $params{schema}->txn_do( sub {
      @result = $params{rs}->search( @{ $params{search} } );
      return unless (@result);
      for my $result_item (@result) {
        $result_item->update( @{ $params{update} } );
      }
  } );
  return \@result;
}

my $data = _retry 15, sub {
  do_update(
    schema => $schema,
    rs     => $thingy_rs,
    search => [ { state => 0, job_id => $job->job_id }, { rows => $self->{batchsize} } ],
    update => [ { state => 1 } ],
  );
};
```

These might also be handy additions to your code. ( Untested )

Comment: +1, but $func->() might return something different in list context -- I'd suggest using wantarray() to handle both cases.

Answer (score 3):

The only real problem I see is the lack of a last statement.  This is how I would write it:

```
sub _retry {
    my ($timeout, $func) = @_;
    for my $try (0 .. $timeout*10) {
        sleep 0.1 if $try;
        eval { $func->(); 1 } or do {
            next if $@ =~ /database is locked/; #ignore this error
            croak $@;                           #but raise any other error
        };
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, I forgot copying the last. It is in my original code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I might use 'return' instead of 'last' (in the code as amended by Chas Owens), but the net effect is the same.  I am also not clear why you multiply the first parameter of your retry function by 10.

IMNSHO, it is far better to (re)factor common skeletal code into a function as you have done than to continually write the same code fragment over and over.  There's too much danger that:

- You have to change the logic - in far too many places
- You forget to edit the logic correctly at some point

These are standard arguments in favour of using functions or equivalent abstractions over inline code.

In other words - good job on creating the function.  And it is useful that Perl allows you to create the functions on the fly (thanks, Larry)!

Comment: The timeout is in seconds and he is sleeping for .1 seconds between tries, so a 1 second timeout will have 10 tries.

Comment: I agree that factoring out such code is a good idea for exactly those reasons.

I still wonder if there's code on CPAN providing a retry mechanism that I could just have used...

Answer (score 0):

[Attempt](http://search.cpan.org/~markf/Attempt-1.01/) by Mark Fowler seems to be pretty close to what I described above. Now, it would be handy if one could specify some sort of exception filter.