# Perl script unable to write to database when executed in crontab despite being able to write if executed manually

Tags: php, mysql, perl, sqlite, cron

I've been wrestling with this issue for awhile now.. and I have tried many solutions, such as:

1. [Why can't DBD::SQLite insert into a database through my Perl CGI script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122885/why-cant-dbdsqlite-insert-into-a-database-through-my-perl-cgi-script)
2. [Why do I get sqlite error, “unable to open database file”?](https://serverfault.com/questions/57596/why-do-i-get-sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file)

### Brief

A few weeks ago, I migrated my server from Laravel 4.0 to another server which is now the latest version of Laravel 5.0.

**In the old server**, I have this Perl file which is a scraper which I run using a crontab every 30 minutes called `getListOfClasses.pl`

Using the following `crontab` command on my **OLD** server, I would run this:

```
0,30 * * * * /var/www/loop/storage/scripts/getListOfClasses.pl  >> /var/www/loop/storage/logs/laravel-scraper.log 2>&1
```

Which executes the scraper in `/var/www/loop/storage/scripts/getListOfClassesFromSubjects.pl` and writes to my database in `/var/www/loop/storage/database.sqlite`

After my move, Laravel 5.0 changed the default database location from `storage` to `database`, so I edited my crontab to reflect that change as well the database name from:

```
my $dbFile = '../storage/database.sqlite';
```

to the new file path location

```
my $dbFile = '../../database/database.sqlite';
```

### The Issue

If I run my scraper manually at:

```
/var/www/schedulizer/storage/scripts/getListOfClasses.pl
```

I am able to scrape just fine. However, if I rely on the crontab to execute the script, I receive the following errors:

```
DBI connect('dbname=../../database/database.sqlite','',...) failed: unable to open database file at /var/www/schedulizer/storage/scripts/getListOfClasses.pl line 22.
```

Line 22 is `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {`. I don't believe this line of code is relevant - I guess my server has issues writing to that database.

The permissions that my SQLite database has is the following:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data root 8845312 Nov  3 00:05 database.sqlite
```

The folder in which the database exists has the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data root       4096 Nov  3 00:05 database
```

These permission levels all are the same as my old server's permission levels for both the database file as well as the folder.. I've also tried `chown` and `chmod 777` on the database file so it has all the permissions possible. Still no luck.

Any one have clues why?

Comment: What user does cron run as? Different from the user that runs the script manually?

Comment: @JRD How do I check this?

Comment: Well, do you edit the crontab file with `crontab -e` or some other way? Also, can post the crontab entry on the new server?

Comment: You could add a logging statement like
`print STDERR "UID=$< EUID=$> ", qx/pwd/;`
and check what you get back from the cron job (you usually get STDERR by mail). The `qx/pwd/` aso checks the current working directory in case that should have changed.

Comment: a couple of quick tips - make sure that the folder has execute permissions for the user and that the file also has execute permissions for the user.  You haven't shown the error message which could be helpful ( ie is the perl module not found or is there permissions issue with the files or directories ). Does the perl executable environment have access to the modules as that user or has the module been installed in a different ENV ?

Comment: Use absolute pathes instead of relative to make sure you access the correct and existing directory. Include a `cd /some/where ;` before your command in the crontab. Is it roots crontab or www-data's? In the latter case, `su` to `www-data` and try to execute the file from where it is run.

Comment: Maybe, first "../" in $dbFile is superflous (in the old value there were only one "../")? Try to test script with full path to database file in $dbFIle variable.

Comment: There are three key differences when running from cron - user, environment, path. Check all of these are as you expect.

Comment: @mbethke do I put that in my Perl script? Is it possible to direct the error message to my scraper-specific log file?

Comment: @PeterScott As far as I know, that's all the error messages I've received (the failed to connect one)

Comment: @syck Oh wow.. Using absolute paths worked..! I am so surprised!! I thought this wouldn't matter at all considering executing it manually yields no issue!! Thanks! Could you post the answer so I could mark it as right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing manually, you probably went to the correct working directory for the script to do the editing. Starting it from any other location would most likely have caused failure as well.

- Use absolute pathes instead of relative to make sure you access the correct and existing directory.
- Include a `cd /some/where ;` before your command in the crontab. Cron sets  your home directory, no matter where the called program sits.

The second proposal is imho the more portable, because it does not require script changes when the location or machine is changed; you simply adapt it in your (machine-specific) crontab.